# react state not being updated

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I am trying to toggle the info window in react-google-maps off and on through a custom component. The toggle method is being called as I checked if it's logged. Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Created by.
 */
import * as React from 'react'
import {Col, Row, Card, CardHeader, CardBody, CardColumns, CardText, CardFooter} from 'reactstrap'
import {InfoWindow, Marker} from 'react-google-maps'

export default class home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isOpen: false
    }

    toggleOpen = () => {
        this.setState(({ isOpen }) => (
            {
                isOpen: !isOpen,
            }
        ));
        if(this.state.isOpen)
            console.log("state is open")
        else
            console.log("state is not open")
    }



    render()
    {
        const { isOpen } = this.state;
        return (
            <Marker
                position={this.props.position}
                onClick={this.toggleOpen}>
                <InfoWindow isOpen={isOpen}>
                    <Card className="hovercard">
                        <Row>
                            <CardColumns sm={6} lg={3}>a
                                <CardHeader>
                                    {this.props.homestay}
                                </CardHeader>
                                <CardText className="avatar">
                                    <img alt="profile img" src={this.props.profilePic}/>
                                </CardText>
                                <div className="info">
                                    <CardText>{this.props.descrip}</CardText>
                                </div>
                                <CardFooter>
                                    {this.props.price}
                                </CardFooter>
                            </CardColumns>
                        </Row>
                    </Card>
                </InfoWindow>
            </Marker>
        )
    }
}
```

The infowindow is not opening when I click it. Any ideas?

EDIT ----
I changed the toggle method as you mentioned but the toggle is still not responding. Here's my project in sandeditor:https://codesandbox.io/s/93258nn8m4

Comment: How did you know it is not opened? by logging into inspector?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to put state in `constructor` for first time initialization or to create instance of the class, However not necessary always but use it to keep best practice.

```
 constructor() {
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    }
  }
```

Also, I don't know if it is the correct way to setState

**change this**

```
toggleOpen = () => {
        this.setState(({ isOpen }) => (
            {
                isOpen: !isOpen,
            }
        ));
        if(this.state.isOpen)
            console.log("state is open")
        else
            console.log("state is not open")
    }
```

**to this**

```
toggleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen},() => {
                if(this.state.isOpen)
                    console.log("state is open")
                else
                    console.log("state is not open")     
            }
        );        
    }
```

**P.S.** [Beware because React setState is asynchronous!](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

**Update**

Just noticed that if you don't define a constructor in the class that is ok. Because [The constructor is dead](https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599).

However, Your transpiler still will generate it in a constructor form which is satisfying.

So that part of your question; setting state without a constructor is fine but to `setState` is definitely not.

Answer (score 0):

This reset the `isOpen` value.Once you are setting to current value and in callback you are toggling it.

```
this.setState(({ isOpen }) => (
            {
                isOpen: !isOpen,
            }
        ));
```

Correct way:

```
this.setState(prevState) => (
            {
                isOpen: !isOpen,
            }
        ));
```